# Xcode Linker Flags Stanford Network Analysis Project (SNAP)

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, flags

I am trying to SNAP with C++ on Xcode. I installed SNAP and provided these two header search paths to Xcode: /usr/local/Cellar/Snap-3.0/snap-core/ and /usr/local/Cellar/Snap-3.0/glib-core/.

But it still produces the error below. I believe I need to fill in "other linker flags" in Xcode, but I can't seem to get it right. Thanks for help.

The C++ Code is below:

```
#include "Snap.h"
int main() {
return 0;
}
```

Error Message Below

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ExeStop(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, int const&)", referenced from:
      TRStr::UnRef() in main.o
      TRStr::~TRStr() in main.o
      TRStr::GetNullRStr() in main.o
  "TStr::GetRStr(char const*)", referenced from:
      TStr::TStr(char const*) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```

Answer (score 2):

It works once I add  -lSnap.o in "other linker flags" in Xcode